# how can i make 2 vertical tabs ( left and right ) work on the same content box in the center>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some vertical tabs and i want to add more, but i want to add the to the right of the first vertical tabs. First ones are on the left and next to them there is the content box, well i want after this content box to be a new set of vertical tabs which will apply on the same content box. Here is an image with what i want ( i made it in photoshop ) : http://s14.postimage.org/4mi4kx15d/what_i_need.jpg

I want the new column to have the same properties as the first column because I want to add more tabs it will be a long and ugly column, but with 2 will be better

Here is what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/26zQS/6/

html

```
<div class="verticalslider" id="textExample">
            <ul class="verticalslider_tabs">
                <li><a href="#">Catedra de Limba si Literatura Romana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Catedra de Matematica</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Catedra de Informatica</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Limba engleza</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Limba Germana</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="verticalslider_contents">
                <li>
                <h2>Catedra de Limba si Literatura Romana</h2></br>
                <p id="profesor">
                Popa Alina </br>
                Nadia Pascu</br>
                </p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <h2>Catedra de Matematica</h2></br>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Ciubotariu Boer-Vlad </br>
                    Diaconu Ilie</br>
                    Gorcea Violin </br>
                    </p>
                </li>

<li>
                <h2>informatica</h2>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Wainblat Gabriela</br>
                    Nistor Ancuta</br>
                </li>

                <li>
                <h2>Limba Engleza</h2>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Wainblat Gabriela</br>
                    Nistor Ancuta</br>
                </li>

                <li>
                <h2>Germana</h2>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Wainblat Gabriela</br>
                    Nistor Ancuta</br>
                </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a simple solution:

html:

```
<ul class="verticalslider_tabs right">
    <li><a href="#">Catedra de Limba si Literatura Romana</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Catedra de Matematica</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Catedra de Informatica</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Limba engleza</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Limba Germana</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="verticalslider_tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Catedra de Limba si Literatura Romana</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Catedra de Matematica</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Catedra de Informatica</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Limba engleza</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Limba Germana</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
   .verticalslider_tabs {
        float: left;
        width: 220px;
    }
    .verticalslider_tabs.right {
        float:right;
    }
    .verticalslider_contents {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/26zQS/19/

Of course it still needs some changes to be normaly functional.

If you're willing to change the source code of the vertical tabs you just have to change one line to make it work.

change :
`activeIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;`

with :
`activeIndex = tabs.index($(this).parent());`

Comment: this idea is good, but my problem is how i change the javascript to work properly on the same content box? css and html are not so difficult , but to make the tabs work on the same box is difficult

Comment: @AdiMicutzu I did a minor change and I suppose it will be ok now.